# combining plot of ggplot and image in R

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I want to combine 3 `image` plots and one `ggplot`in one figure.

1. when I use `par(mfrow=c(4,1))`, it plots 3 `image`s in one figure, and the `ggplot` in another separate figure.
2. And when I use `plot_grid(p1, p2,p3,p4, labels=c("A", "B","C","D"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)`, which is used for combining `ggplot`s, it plots only the ggplot in its location, and other image plots are plotted separately.

   what is the solution to have all of this four plots in one figure?

Comment: What sort of object are you plotting with `image`? Are there `ggplot` equivalents for that object type?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf

Comment: I got it, Thanks for your response. I think I did not search very well